# Navigation from component to another componet

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have login component and dashboard. My application entry point is login page. After successful login, I want move to main page(dashboard & navigation).

I tried this like the following but its not working. After login not able to move to dashboard.
My login Component is

```
var React = require('react');
var {Link} = require('react-router');
var Dashboard = require('Dashboard');

var Login = React.createClass ({
onFormSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   <Dashboard /> 
},
render: function(){
  return (
<div>
  <h1 className="text-center">Login</h1>
  <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <input type="text" ref="username"/>

        <button className="button">Login</button>
  </form>
 </div>
 )
 } 
 });

module.exports = Login;
```

My Dashboard component is

```
 var React = require('react');
 var Nav = require('Nav');

 var Dashboard = (props) => {
   return (
     <div>
      <Nav/>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="columns medium-6 large-4 small-centered">
        {props.children}
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 );
}

module.exports = Dashboard;
```

Main app.jsx file is

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory} = require('react-router');
var Login = require('Login');
var Dashboard = require('Dashboard');
var About = require('About');
var Examples = require('Examples');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Login}>
     <Route component={Dashboard}>
       <Route path="about" component={About}/>
       <Route path="examples" component={Examples}/>
    </Route>
   </Route>
  </Router>,
 document.getElementById('app')
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onFormSumit()` should be like this

```
onFormSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   window.location.href = '/dashboard'
},
```

And your `<Router/>` in **app.jsx** should be like this

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={Login} />
   <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
   <Route path="about" component={About}/>
   <Route path="examples" component={Examples}/>
 </Router>
```

This will make the browser redirect to `/dashboard` on form submit. That redirected url(`/dashboard`) will be captured by the `<Router/>` and the component for that `path` will be rendered.

**[Update]**

In your `express`, you nee to add the path so that it always returns the `index.html` page. Add this

```
app.get(['/', '/dashboard'], function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('./path to your index.html file')
})
```

or you can do the following also

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
   res.sendfile('./path to your index.html file')
})
```

For further read, check [this](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: When I am doing like this, getting Cannot GET /dashboard

Comment: Are you using `express` in node js?

Comment: Yes, I am using express in node js

Comment: @user2194838 Updated the answer. plz check!

Comment: Now its redirecting to dashboard but showing login page only. Url was http://localhost:3000/#/?_k=qdl2jx after clicking on submit url becomes http://localhost:3000/dashboard#/?_k=8zf137

Comment: use `history={browserHistory}` instead of  `history={hashHistory}`

Comment: Still same problem showing login page only but now url becomes http://localhost:3000/dashboard

Comment: @user2194838 Hey just updated the answer. The route path should be `dashboard` not `/dashboard`

Comment: Its working if i am placing Dashboard router separately not inside Login Router.